# Keep getting warning: Invalid DOM property `autocomplete`. Did you mean `autoComplete`?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I keep gettin this error: **"Invalid DOM property `autocomplete`. Did you mean `autoComplete`?"** when I'm compiling my react project on ***Google Chrome***.
When i've tried compiling code on **Firefox** everything worked fine.

I want to ask a question: How can fix this error on Google Chrome? And why only on Google Chrome this error being displayed?

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";

import {
Container, Col, Form,
FormGroup, Label, Input,
Button,
} from 'reactstrap';

export default class Register extends React.Component{

render() {

    return (
        <div>

            <Container>
                <h2>Sign In</h2>
                <Form>
                    <Col>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label>Email</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                id="exampleEmail"
                                placeholder="myemail@email.com"

                              autocomplete = "email"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="Phone Number"
                                name="Phone Number"
                                id="exampleNumber"
                                placeholder="37060289225"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="RepeatPassword">Repeat Password</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="password"
                                name="Repeat Password"
                                id="RepeatPassword"
                                placeholder="********"

                               autocomplete="new-password"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="examplePassword">Password</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                id="examplePassword"
                                placeholder="********"

                               autocomplete = "new-password"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>

                    <Button>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: JSX is not the exact same as HTML. `autoComplete` is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when using the prop autocomplete in your input, it wants you to replace it with autoComplete="new-password"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a, link: [GitHub Problem](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2882)

This i'd mark as a duplicate
as there is:
[Cheat Sheet][2]
[2]: https://medium.com/react-tutorials/react-properties-ef11cd55caa0 too.

I would, Say these links, Would help you.

Hope this, Will help!